# Are there a way to receive and handle http request in .NET UWP Apps?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, httprequest

I've a UWP App, with a `MainPage` that displays a radio button emulating a lamp (true = on, false = off).

I need to expose this property and interact with it, with http requests.
Specifically, from the client I'll call the server running the app, with some things in query string, like `192.168.1.1/?on`.

When the app receives the request, it will do something like turn on the lamp (set radiobutton to true), and show this in real time in the UI.

Is it possible?
I've tried some libraries like `Restup`, but I think they are specific for sending requests, not to receive.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in functionality for an HTTP server in UWP... but you might not need that. Based on your requirement, you can make-do with opening a socket and listening for incoming connection/data on that socket.

You can take a look at the documentation describing that functionality [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets)

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly why Restup was build, take a look at [the one-pager](https://github.com/tomkuijsten/restup/wiki/One-pager) to get you going. Controlling your lamp will be pretty easy.

Note: I'm the author of Restup